# How to understand this crash report? SIGSEGV

Tags: css, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

I get this crash quite often recently, device iPhone 5s, SDk: 9.1
I can't seem to reproduce this bug. The log is taken from a 3rd party crash reporter (Testfairy).

It's annoying as I can't figure out what's causing it..

```
Crashed Thread: 14
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x19a6f1bdc objc_msgSend (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 28
1   Foundation                          0x186bd68d4 _writeJSONValue (in Foundation) + 96
2   Foundation                          0x186bd8cc0 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke (in Foundation) + 236
3   CoreFoundation                      0x185b6e4f4 __65-[__NSDictionaryI enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation) + 88
4   CoreFoundation                      0x185b5c198 -[__NSDictionaryI enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation) + 224
5   Foundation                          0x186bd844c _writeJSONObject (in Foundation) + 360
6   Foundation                          0x186bd69fc _writeJSONValue (in Foundation) + 392
7   Foundation                          0x186bd8ea8 ___writeJSONArray_block_invoke (in Foundation) + 144
8   CoreFoundation                      0x185b13990 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation) + 132
9   CoreFoundation                      0x185b13828 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation) + 212
10  Foundation                          0x186bd86a8 _writeJSONArray (in Foundation) + 300
11  Foundation                          0x186bd6a9c _writeJSONValue (in Foundation) + 552
12  Foundation                          0x186bd8cc0 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke (in Foundation) + 236
13  CoreFoundation                      0x185b6e4f4 __65-[__NSDictionaryI enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation) + 88
14  CoreFoundation                      0x185b5c198 -[__NSDictionaryI enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation) + 224
15  Foundation                          0x186bd844c _writeJSONObject (in Foundation) + 360
16  Foundation                          0x186bd69fc _writeJSONValue (in Foundation) + 392
17  Foundation                          0x186bd682c -[_NSJSONWriter dataWithRootObject:options:error:] (in Foundation) + 140
18  Foundation                          0x186bd7888 +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] (in Foundation) + 348
19  MyApp                               0x1003721e8 -[TestFairyCommunicator sendEvents:toServer:withSession:] (in MyApp) (TestFairyCommunicator.m:219)
20  MyApp                               0x10036fa70 -[TestFairy send:events:] (in MyApp) (TestFairy.m:1260)
21  MyApp                               0x100369394 -[TFEventsTracker sendEvents] (in MyApp) (TFEventsTracker.m:66)
22  MyApp                               0x10036e32c -[TestFairy checkForegroundViewController] (in MyApp) (TestFairy.m:924)
23  MyApp                               0x10036df34 -[TestFairy collectMetrics] (in MyApp) (TestFairy.m:886)
24  Foundation                          0x186b5fc80 __NSThread__start__ (in Foundation) + 1000
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x19b113b28 _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x19b113a8c _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x19b111028 thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
```

Do you have any ideas on what causes this crash?

Comment: Are doing any JSON serialisation?

Comment: @JacobKing Yes. The problem is, I can't find out where exactly this crashes. there is a lot of JSON serialisation in the app..

Comment: did you tried with exception break point?

Comment: @himanth I can't seem to reproduce this bug. The log is taken from a 3rd party crash reporter (Testfairy)

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint here `TestFairyCommunicator.m:219` and check that your events data structure is sound:

- The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
- All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
- All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
- Numbers are not NaN or
  infinity.

Directly quoting: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsjsonserialization

Comment: I can't put break points in Testfairy classes, it's a 3rd party library for crash reporting. I can't seem to reproduce this bug, it only happens for a user with iPhone 5s SDK:9.1. It's didn't even crash on a simulator or other devices.